# Верстка сайта если есть дизайн psd

Tags: вёрстка, css

Добрый день,
как верстать правильно?т.е у меня есть макет psd, разбитый на слои, и что, мне его резать и экспортировать или лучше накодить адаптивную сетку и вырезать только то, что нельзя сделать в CSS?или сохранять из слоев? использовать ли раскройку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй использовать Fireworks, очень удобно резать макет, один раз все выделил, экспортировал, и все.

Comment: спасибо, fireworks оценил, круто, только немного макет исказил почему-то (текст в одном месте)вопрос можно закрывать

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно вырезать только то что с помощью css не сделать. Пользуйся "save for web & devises" так картинки будут оптимизироваться, и старайся меньше вырезать - больше делать на css

Comment: спасибо:))save for web & devises это ясно конечно)